# Moving order creation to when customer completes checkout

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-oscar

our eCommerce site using `Django-oscar` currently handles order creation after the user pays, which can result in the issue described in https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/2891. We would like to switch to creating the order with a `pending` status once the user completes checkout, and then fulfilling it once payment goes through.

We're currently unsure what the consequences of this are, so I was hoping to find some examples of this order creation flow that I could look to for our transition. Does `Django-oscar` use this flow by default out of the box, or are there existing open source applications that we could check for examples?

Thanks in advance for any help

**Technical details:**

```
Python version: 2.7  
Django version: 1.11  
Oscar version: 1.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat broad question which it's difficult to give a concise answer to, but some suggestions for how to implement this:

- Oscar doesn't make many assumptions about what your order workflow is. It's up to you to define a [pipeline](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/settings.html#oscar-order-status-pipeline) that describes what order status you want, and what transitions an order can make between statuses. Once defined, it's easy for staff to set order statuses from the dashboard, or to do this programatically with `Order.set_status()`.
- If you implement a `pending` status, then you may need to override some of the default behaviour that takes place in the [`OrderPlacementMixin`](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/a22f4991b036890b2d90839cd2c4a03e22258255/src/oscar/apps/checkout/mixins.py#L29) when an order is created - e.g., you may not want to send an order confirmation email at this stage, in which case you need to override `send_confirmation_message()`, and instead send an email at a later time (e.g., in response to a `order_status_changed` signal.
- Totally depends on use case, but you may need to think about what happens if, say, payment doesn't go through. Asking the customer to start all over again may not be ideal, in which case you may want a way to pre-populate a new basket with the items from the failed order.

Don't have public source code for the above, but it's all possible with Oscar.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer, I appreciate it. Are there any common pitfalls or gotchas you can think of that might come from modifying an existing order status pipeline to include a `pending` status?

Comment: None that I can think of - modifying a pipeline is relatively straightforward to do.

Comment: One more question: I know you said that Oscar tries not to make assumptions about what the order workflow is, but do you think there is a good place in the documentation that I (or someone else) could update to suggest this as a possible flow for orders?  Just so that others don't accidentally fall into the same trap that my team did

Comment: See https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_set_up_order_processing.html#how-to-set-up-order-processing - happy for you to suggest improvements to that documentation via PR. It does try to explain that Oscar is quite agnostic to order workflows.